# Deriving joint & marginal cdfs

Tags: probability

Suppose I have joint pdf $f_{XY}(x,y)$

The marginal pdf of, say, X is $$f_X(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y) dy$$

The marginal cdf of X is $$ \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{x}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y) dy  dx$$ Right?

But what about joint cdf? Isn't it also $$\int_{-\infty}^{x}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y) dy  dx$$ as the opposite to $$f_{XY}(x,y) = \frac{F^2_{XY}(x,y)}{dy dx}$$?

Comment: The joint CDF is $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^y\int_{-\infty}^x f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$.

Comment: Stefan, one more question. Derivative of marginal cdf $\rightarrow$ marginal pdf. Derivative of joint cdf $\rightarrow$ nothing meaningful. Mixed partial derivative of joint cdf  $\rightarrow$ joint pdf. Right?

Comment: That sounds about right. Taking the derivative of the joint cdf with respect to e.g. $y$ just gives you the inner-most integral.

Comment: Stefan, thank you for your help!

Comment: In Stefan's answer, I would use different symbols for the integration limits $(x,y)$ as in $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and the integration variables as in ${\rm d}u \, {\rm d}v$. Having the same variable in the integrand and as a limit of integration is weird and inconsistent.